# Get a html value in as3

Tags: html, actionscript-3, actionscript

Hello so i am loading html source in flash like so

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('http://www.google.com'));
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

            function onComplete(e:Event):void {
                trace(e.target.data);
}
```

this will trace the html source of google.com. i want to know if there's a way to trace the value of the  < title > < / title > or any other attributes in the html that was loaded from e.target.data?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use the [`XML`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) class to parse the HTML, but often this is not the case because the rules for XML are slightly different and stricter compared to HTML.

I suggest looking for a [HTML parser](http://as3htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) that you're comfortable with.

If you only need to extract the `<title>` tag, you *can* use Regex, though I strongly suggest you avoid it.

Comment: I think this tutorial is quite explanatory as well for the OP: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ed4.html

Comment: @adaam The `HTMLLoader` is only available in AIR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ExternalInterface** class to interact with Javascript/HTML.

You can call JavaScript  method and get results returned as follows:

```
 var result:Object = ExternalInterface.call("javaScriptMethod()", "parameter1", "parameter2");
 if (result != null)
 {
     return new Number(result);
 }
```

Here is the API reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: Can you explain the process of using ExternalInterface to trigger JavaScript which will load and parse some XML, with the results being fed back to ActionScript?